# Modeling following constraints in MILP

Tags: mathematical-modeling, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

I want to know how I should formulate the following constraints in my MIP problem?

$$x= x_1 z_1+ \dots +x_n z_n  \text{ and }
  y_1 \le y \le y_n  \text{ and }
  z_1+\dots+z_n=1$$

OR

$$y= y_1 w_1+\dots+y_n w_n \text{ and }
  x_1 \le x \le x_n  \text{ and }
  w_1+\dots+w_n=1$$

$x$ and $y$ are continuous variables. $z_1,\dots,z_n$ and $w_1,\dots,w_n$ are binary decision variables.
$x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $y_1,\dots,y_n$ are parameters.

Comment: what is the problem exactly? if $\{x_i,y_i\}$ are constants, these are usual linear constraints?

Comment: Do you know that $x_1 \le \dots \le x_n$ and $y_1 \le \dots \le y_n$?

Comment: @RobPratt I didn't understand what you mean. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Are your $x_i$ and $y_i$ values sorted?

Comment: @RobPratt You mentioned an important point. No. they may not be sorted. The following answer is correct for the case that they are sorted. For my problem It is better to define parameters xmin=min(x1, ..., xn) and ymin=min(y1, ..., yn), xmax=max(x1, ..., xn) and ymax=max(y1, ..., yn)  and use them in tha last two terms of first and second equations in the following answer instead of x1, xn, y1 and yn.

Comment: And do you care about the values of $w_i$ in the first case or $z_i$ in the second case? @prubin's formulation fixes them to 0.

Comment: I'm asking whether it is OK that $t=0$ implies $w_i=0$ and that $t=1$ implies $z_i=0$?

Comment: @Robpratt yes, that 's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual big-M approach is to introduce a binary variable $t$ as in @prubin's formulation and then impose the following constraints:
\begin{align}
x_{\min} \le x &\le x_{\max} \tag{1} \\
y_{\min} \le y &\le y_{\max} \tag{2} \\
\left(x_{\min} - \sum_i x_i\right) t \le x - \sum_i x_i z_i &\le x_{\max} \cdot t \tag{3} \\
-t \le \sum_i z_i - 1 &\le (n-1) t \tag{4} \\
\left(y_{\min} - \sum_i y_i\right) (1-t) \le y - \sum_i y_i w_i &\le y_{\max}(1-t) \tag{5} \\
-(1-t) \le \sum_i w_i - 1 &\le (n-1) (1-t) \tag{6}
\end{align}

Constraints $(1)$ and $(2)$ are valid for both sides of the desired disjunction.
Constraints $(3)$ and $(4)$ enforce $$t=0 \implies \left(x = \sum_i x_i z_i \land \sum_i z_i = 1\right).$$
Constraints $(5)$ and $(6)$ enforce $$t=1 \implies \left(y = \sum_i y_i w_i \land \sum_i w_i = 1\right).$$

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Could you please introduce me a refrence that explains more about the big-M approach that you mentioned?

Comment: Model Building in Mathematical Programming by H. Paul Williams.  Also https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-m

Answer (score 1):

Brace yourself, the notation is about to get a little ugly.

Let me list the variables first. In addition to $x$ and $y$ (continuous), we will have $z_1,\dots,z_n\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ and $w_1,\dots,w_n\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$, plus $\hat{z},\tilde{z},\hat{w},\tilde{w}\in [0,1]$ and one more binary variable $t\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$. The constraints will be as follows:\begin{align}
x & =\sum_{i}x_{i}z_{i}+x_{1}\hat{z}+x_{n}\tilde{z}\\
y & =\sum_{i}y_{i}w_{i}+y_{1}\hat{w}+y_{n}\tilde{w}\\
\sum_{i}z_{i} & =1-t\\
\hat{z}+\tilde{z} & =t\\
\sum_{i}w_{i} & =t\\
\hat{w}+\tilde{w} & =1-t.
\end{align}

If $t=0$, the fourth equation zeroes out the last two terms of the first equation and the third equation plus the first equation result in $x$ being one of the $x_i$. Meanwhile, the fifth equation zeroes out the summation in the second equation and the sixth equation and what's left of the second equation make $y$ a convex combination of the endpoints $y_1$, $y_n$, so basically any value in the interval $[y_1,y_n]$. If $t=1$, the reverse occurs.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help. I know the notation isn't good. But I don't know how to write math expressions here.

Comment: Actually, what I meant was that I was making the notation worse (by throwing in hats and tildes). I generally don't like using $x$ or $y$ for parameters (or letters early in the English alphabet for variables), but in your case it makes perfect sense (if somewhat tricky reading) to have $x_i$ and $y_i$ be parameters.